# When I start dradis it shows this

Tags: software-installation

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.9 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:443
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:105:in `database_configuration': Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: (RuntimeError)
Could not load database configuration. No such file - 
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/nitesh/dradis-git/server/engines/core/app/models/dradis/core/log.rb:3:in `<module:Core>'
    from /home/nitesh/dradis-git/server/engines/core/app/models/dradis/core/log.rb:2:in `<module:Dradis>'
    from /home/nitesh/dradis-git/server/engines/core/app/models/dradis/core/log.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
    from /home/nitesh/dradis-git/server/config/initializers/z_01_clear_transient_data.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    from /home/nitesh/dradis-git/server/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nitesh/dradis-git/server/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /home/nitesh/dradis-git/server/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/nitesh/dradis-git/server/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/nitesh/dradis-git/server/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nitesh/dradis-git/server/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /home/nitesh/dradis-git/server/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/nitesh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nitesh/dradis-git/server/bin/spring:16:in `require'
    from /home/nitesh/dradis-git/server/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you install Dradis? The installation guide here should get you up and running: https://dradis.com/ce/documentation/install_git.html

We have others running on Ubuntu: http://discuss.dradisframework.org/t/problem-running-dradis-with-redis-on-ubuntu/339 so let us know if you keep running into problems!